# How can I add home-page sections in any page, other than home-page in my Shopify Store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

in my Shopify Store, I can see that I can add different sections in home page, using my theme customizer. Is there anyway, I can add the same sections or similar to other pages? I want my other pages also look good. For example, I want to add slideshow or 'image with text' section in any page, which are only available to home page via theme customizer. Is there any way or any app that can do that? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that via this app: https://apps.shopify.com/pluspage
It's called PlusPage listed in Shopify Store.
They have also documents and tutorials here: https://pluspage.plusapps.dev/tutorials/
Also here is a video link of the app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlo3hU129So&t=95s